# Android Studio Generate JavaDoc errors

Tags: java, android-studio, javadoc

I am attempting to generate a JavaDoc for my project. To do so, I use Tools > Generate JavaDoc. I check Whole Project and set the output directory. It starts to work then returns with

```
error: package android.content does not exist
import android.content.Context;
```

Along with a bunch of other package does not exist errors and

```
cannot access ViewGroup
public class MainMenu extends AppCompatActivity {
       ^
  class file for android.view.ViewGroup not found
```

Thus far I haven't been able to find any sort of solution. My project builds and runs fine on both the emulator and actual devices. Any thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find a work around. I loaded my project in intelliJ IDEA, and while it still showed those errors, it still was able to generate the javadoc that correctly contains all the classes and methods needed.

Comment: Same case for me, getting error in AS while generating javadocs but it works in IntelliJ IDEA. Thanks for giving the workaround, it may help for a time-being but still curious to know, the right fix such errors in Android studio.